# How to query by ScalarListType in SQLAlchemy-Utils?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The following does not work:

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import ScalarListType
class Company(db.Model):
    email_domains = db.Column(ScalarListType())

Company.query.filter(Company.email_domains.contains(email_domain)).one_or_none()
```

Comment: What does the error log tell you? I'm sure you're right, it doesn't work, but I'm also sure it's possible to add more detail to your question.

Comment: @Charlie it simply does not find any records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but you have to wrap the string in a list.

```
Company.query.filter(Company.email_domains.contains([email_domain])).one_or_none()
```